# Redshift table with 0 Rows Consuming Disk Space

Tags: amazon-redshift

i have a number of tables where all the rows have been deleted from.  I then ran a vacuum full on these tables but they are still showing as consuming disk space.  Any idea why this happens.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete all the rows from a Redshift table, perform a `truncate` operation rather than a `delete` operation.

Further, **if you do not intend to retain the table or you know that you'll never populate them again**, simply drop them. Remember, dropping a table takes away all the privileges and grants sanctioned on it.

Coming to your question, this has happened with me as well. I hope you're querying system tables to get an approximation of the table size. Give some time to Redshift to stabilise and then run the query to check disk space again. The space occupied by that table should be 0 (or the table would rather not appear in your result set, indicating that all the space occupied has been released.

Also, along with `vacuum`, do run `analyze` : [**Vacuum and Analyze - Amazon Redshift Documentation**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/tutorial-loading-data-vacuum.html)

You may use:

```
select
    trim(pgdb.datname) as Database,
    trim(pgn.nspname) as Schema,
    trim(a.name) as Table,
    b.mbytes,
    a.rows from (
    select db_id, id, name, sum(rows) as rows
    from stv_tbl_perm a
    group by db_id, id, name ) as a join pg_class as pgc on pgc.oid = a.id join pg_namespace as pgn on pgn.oid = pgc.relnamespace join pg_database as pgdb on pgdb.oid = a.db_id join (
    select tbl, count(*) as mbytes
    from stv_blocklist
    group by tbl ) b on a.id = b.tbl order by mbytes desc, a.db_id, a.name;
```

to check the space consumed by different tables.

Comment: Yeah thats exactly what i'm using to get the table sizes.  Tables are showing 500mb's used and 0 rows.  I just issued a truncate to the tables and that cleared up all the space.  Still doesnt explain why vacuum wont clear the space from a delete